# Python: Getting tokens and NER tags from string indexes

Tags: python

I have a string and along with tag information in a dictionary for that string.

```
string = "Steve works in Meta Graphics"
tags = {"tags": [(0, 4, "PER"), (15, 27, "ORG")]}
```

I need to use this information and produce the following representation of the string.

```
string_tag_tuples = [("Steve", "PER"), ("works", "O"), ("in", "O"), ("Meta Graphics", "ORG")]
```

Its easier to get tokens and their associated tag from provided information in `labels`, however, how to assign `O` tag to other tokens in string and get the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it in two seperate steps. First, recognize the tagged portions of the text and store the other ones as strings. Then, transform everything stored as a string to elements tagged with `"0"`.

```
string = "Steve works in Meta Graphics"
tags = {"tags": [(0, 4, "PER"), (15, 27, "ORG")]}

## Recognize the tagged strings:

tags['tags'] = sorted(tags['tags'])
ct = 0
i = 0
result = []
cs = ''
while not i >= len(string):
    if i in range(tags['tags'][ct][0],tags['tags'][ct][1]):
        if len(cs)>0:result.append(cs)
        cs = ''
        result.append((string[tags['tags'][ct][0]:tags['tags'][ct][1]+1],tags['tags'][ct][2]))
        i=tags['tags'][ct][1]
        ct=+1
    else:
        cs+=string[i]
    i+=1
if len(cs)>0:result.append(cs)

print('First step:',result)

## Tag the untagged portions of the list:

final_result = []
for e in result:
    if type(e)==tuple:
        final_result.append(e)
    else:
        words = e.split(' ')
        for w in words:
            if len(w)>0: final_result.append((w,'0'))

print('Second step:',final_result)
```

The output of this program would be:

```
First step: [('Steve', 'PER'), ' works in ', ('Meta Graphics', 'ORG')]
Second step: [('Steve', 'PER'), ('works', '0'), ('in', '0'), ('Meta Graphics', 'ORG')]
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is about labeling.

Various libs use their own scheme, I used spacy, it has BILOU tags for achieving this.
https://spacy.io/api/goldparse#biluo_tags_from_offsets

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution,

```
string = "Steve works in Meta Graphics"
tags = {"tags": [(0, 4, "PER"), (15, 27, "ORG")]}
```

sort tag's based on start index & find the missing index(s), in above case `5-14` would missing index.

```
tags_ = tags['tags']

sorted_ = sorted(tags_, key=lambda x : x[0], reverse=True)

gaps = []
for i, j in zip(sorted_, sorted_[1:]):
    gaps.append((j[1] + 1, i[0] - 1, 'O'))

tags_.extend(gaps)

# print(tags_) [(0, 4, 'PER'), (15, 27, 'ORG'), (5, 14, 'O')]
```

finally go throught the sorted index(s), using splicing extract & update tag_result.

```
tag_result = []

for s, e, tag in sorted(tags_, key=lambda x: x[0]):
    if tag == "O":
        tag_result.extend([(v, "O") for v in string[s:e].strip().split()])
    else:
        tag_result.append((string[s:e], tag))
```

---

```
[('Stev', 'PER'), ('works', 'O'), ('in', 'O'), ('Meta Graphic', 'ORG')]
```